# What does "Difficulty god of gods mode" imply?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

A cross-stitch pattern of the original style. Difficulty god of gods mode. Guess I should start practicing.

What does  "Difficulty god of gods mode" imply?

She said, "Oh my God, pattern of stitch?"

Can you explain that, please?
Thank you

Comment: [Please use caps for the pronoun I and please punctuate your questions. It's *cross-stitch pattern* with a hyphen. Finally, please do not use SMS messaging style, Thanks.] I have fixed it but we still don't understand your context. Where did you find that? In a novel?

Answer (score 1):

The gods are often thought of as being very powerful creatures. The god of gods would by implication be exceptionally powerful. So something where you have to enter your god of gods mode in order to complete the cross-stich would be exceptionally difficult. That is why the write ended with suggesting that they needed to start practising before attempting it.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick google search explains: **The term “god mode” comes from the gamer scene, where it refers to cheats that make players immortal.**

The writer resorts to the hyperbole "god of gods mode" as a metaphor for some even higher, more powerful state, necessary to carry out the extremely difficult task in hand.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_mode

Comment: In gaming, god mode is also a legitimate admin mode; the cheats have found a way into what is actually useful to the game's owners.

Comment: Most native speakers wouldn't understand the expression!